# OnKeyPress event not being triggered for ListBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I'm trying to get the `OnKeyPress` event to work for a ASP.NET ListBox which renders itself as a SELECT element in HTML. After doing some search, a couple of site seems to suggest that it is supported, but the event just does not seem to trigger and call my JavaScript code. It seems to trigger for another edit box on the same page, but does not do it for the SELECT element.

I want to use the `OnKeyPress` event so I could retrieve the ASCII code, whereas `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` returns the key code instead.

I'm currently using IE7 and I was wondering if the `OnKeyPress` event is supported by SELECT elements?

Here is how I am doing it in the aspx file:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" Width="306px" SelectionMode="Single"
  Rows="15" CssClass="myListBoxStyle" DataSourceID="myDataSource"
  onchange="myListBoxOnChange(this)"
  onkeypress="myListBoxOnKeyPress(this)" />
```

Comment: i'm using chrome and i'm not getting any presses :(  http://jsfiddle.net/nJbzy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. It seems that I had an `onkeydown="return false"` in the ASPX code of my ListBox element which canceled the `onkeypress` event from happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your codebehind (page_load for ex.) specify

```
yourSelectList.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "YourJavascriptMethodCallHere()");
```

this will call the client side javascript. If you want to process the key on the *server side* (added for additional info), check out: http://forums.asp.net/t/1281277.aspx/1

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", Page.GetPostBackEventReference(DropDownList1,"onkeypress"));
```

Comment: I did that in the page_load of my code behind and it isn't working: `myListBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "myListBoxOnKeyPress(this);");`